# XAMDataGrid column template

Tags: wpf, infragistics

i have to show Text and Graphical status in one(same) column of the XAMDataGrid.
can please someone suggest me template for this.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways you can accomplish this.  The first is to use a Style targeting the CellValuePresenter where you change the Template.  If you are not editing the values, this is the recommended approach and there is an example in the [Embedding a Custom Control in a Field](http://help.infragistics.com/NetAdvantage/WPF/Current/CLR4.0/?page=xamDataPresenter_Embedding_a_Custom_Control_in_a_Field.html) help topic.

The second way to do this is to create a custom ValueEditor which is better if you need to allow editing.  You may be able to use the ControlHostEditor that Andrew Smith provides in the sample in his [Hosting WPF Controls in a XamDataGrid Cell](http://www.infragistics.com/community/blogs/andrew_smith/archive/2009/03/27/hosting-wpf-controls-in-a-xamdatagrid-cell.aspx) blog post.

Comment: thanks alhalama, yesterday i achieved through  Style targeting the CellValuePresenter.