# Formatting numeric field without using ToString()

Tags: c#

How can I format the numeric fields without using `ToString("#,###0.####")` which are calculated at run-time on the basis of other fields.

As using this method converts the numeric fields to string due to which their alignment changes to left in the columns in the `XamDataGrid` of the application.

Please provide any kind of help.

Comment: After `Tostring` why not convert back to Number by using `Convert` ??

Comment: I have not used infragistics controls yet, so i cant post an actual answer, but since it is still a WPF control i believe that you can specify something like a Column Template or Cell Style which will handle value format and alignment. This http://stackoverflow.com/q/19836856/3909293 can be helpful for the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

you can add a style to your Field, inside of the XamDataGrid FieldLayout:

```
<igDP:XamDataGrid.FieldLayouts>
  <igDP:FieldLayout Key="Layout1">
    <igDP:Field Name="PropertyInViewModel" Label="Property Label">
      <igDP:Field.Settings>
        <igDP:FieldSettings EditAsType="{x:Type sys:Double}">
          <igDP:FieldSettings.EditorStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Editors:XamNumericEditor}" >
              <Setter Property="Format" Value="#,###0.####" />
            </Style>
          </igDP:FieldSettings.EditorStyle>
        </igDP:FieldSettings>
      </igDP:Field.Settings>
    </igDP:Field>
  </igDP:FieldLayout>
</igDP:XamDataGrid>
```